# CMake target_compile_options does not recognize a target when using CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE

Tags: cmake, makefile, cross-compiling

I am trying to set different linker flags per target.

My setup is:

- CMakeFiles.txt
- cmakescripts/platform_ABC.cmake
- cmakescripts/platform_XYZ.cmake

The CMakeFiles.txt defines two executables: targetA and targetB

The platform_xxxx.cmake file define the custom platform build / link  settings.

**How can I set two different setting for targetA and targetB in the platform_ABC.cmake?**

The build command:

`cmake . -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="cmakescripts/platform_ABC.cmake"`

Using the target_compile_options(targetA PUBLIC LD_FLAGS "-Wl,mapfile.txt") will fail with error:

```
CMake Error at cmakescripts/platform_ABC.cmake:74 (targetA):
  Cannot specify compile definitions for target "targetA"
  which is not built by this project.
```

Comment: In CMake a toolchain script is executed when `project` command is called for the first time. At that time executable/library targets are not created yet. Moreover, it is not a purpose of a toolchain script to modify settings for a specific targets. Regular toolchain script just defines how executables and libraries should be compiled/link in **general**. However, a toolchain script may define some (custom) variables, which could be read by the project. Or it could call target-independent commands like `add_link_options`.

Comment: BTW, the command `target_compile_options(targetA PUBLIC LD_FLAGS "-Wl,mapfile.txt")` looks weird by itself: `-W` denotes a **linker** flag, but command `target_compile_options` is for **compiler** flags only.

Comment: You are correct regarding the linker, its should be target_link_options.
You wrote "is not a purpose of a toolchain script to modify settings for a specific targets". What should I do if I want to add "-g" for targetA but leave debug option empty for targetB?

Comment: "What should I do if I want to add "-g" for targetA but leave debug option empty for targetB?" - Just call `target_compile_options(targetA PRIVATE -g)` in the **CMakeLists.txt**. If you feel that different compilers will require different compiler options for build-with-debug-information, then you may select the option according to `CMAKE_CXX_COMPLER_ID` variable or by trying different options via `try_compile` mechanism. A toolchain script should describe only fundamental platform features, which cannot be deduced by the project itself.

Comment: Ok thanks, will try. Another question on the same subject.
How can I specify a different compilation flag for a small set of source for targetA, for example set "-o2" for files a.cc and b.cc, but "-o0" for the rest of the sources?

Comment: There is [COMPILE_OPTIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html) property, which can be set for specific source files using [set_source_files_properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_source_files_properties.html) command.